# Kivy - Error: "object has no attribute" when I called it from .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

When I run the next part of code:

> class VState(State):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, name='', stateType=None, **kwargs):
>     super(VState, self).__init__(**kwargs)      
>     self.vBackground = 'my_background'
>     self.name = name
>     
> def setBackgroundImage(self):
>
>   print (self.vBackground)
>
>   return 'gui/my_background_image'
> ```

it will be done. When I call setBackgroundImage() method from .kv file, I get an error: "AttributeError: 'VState' object has no attribute 'vBackground'"

.kv file:

> ...
>
> source: 'atlas://' + root.setBackgroundImage()

but when I run code above without referencing to any attribute, it will be done again... Without line

> print (self.vBackground)

it will be done. Why I can't refer to any attributes from kv file?

Thanks for something ideas...

Comment: How's the rest of your `.kv` file which you aren't showing?  Does the one rule you show us appear within a top-level `VState:` to ensure `root` is an instance of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kv is first evaluated during the widget `__init__`, which in this case happens in your super call *before* you set self.vBackground.

You can instead change the order to

```
self.vBackground = 'my_background'
super(VState, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

It may be even better to use a StringProperty.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you.